# Value used in formula of wrong data type

Tags: function, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been trying to figure this error out for the past few days with no luck. I am hoping one of you would be able to help. I am getting "value used in formula of wrong data type.

Quick explanation:
convert functions like this one to its corresponding text (20054/18393)*100.0
the 5 digit numbers are Field IDs that refer to questions.

ID Question
20054 How many days of year do you work
18393 How many days of vacation do you get a year

The result I am trying to get to is (How many days of year do you work / How many days of vacation do you get a year) *100.0
It could be easily done manually if it was just a hand full. I have over 2600 formulas that need to be converted.
I created this function below which is resulting in the error mentioned in the title. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Here is my function

```
Function Test(sInput As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim num As String
Dim Text, a, str, shortname As String

For i = 1 To Len(sInput)
    a = Mid(sInput, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(a) Then
        num = num & a
        Text = ""
    Else
        If a = "." Then
            num = num & a
        Else
            'search for num value in second sheet short name
            shortname = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WorksheetFunction.Int(num), Worksheets("questionlist").Range("A3:F2537"), 5, False)
            num = ""
        End If

        Text = shortname & a
        shortname = ""
    End If
    str = str & Text
Next

Test = str
End Function
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error when you step through it?  Also, while it's not causing the error, please realize that your third DIM statement actually creates Variants, not strings.  You have to individually apply the AS to each variable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Lance, I changed the DIM statements like you suggested. When I do the step through it does not break at any specific line. The function executes and the i get a #Value in the cell.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain What input & output to the function are expected!

Comment: When doing the step-through, use the Locals (or Immediate) window to look at your variables' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because you are passing blank value to `INT Function` in the line

```
 WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WorksheetFunction.Int(num), Worksheets("questionlist").Range("A3:F2537"), 5, False)
```

To reproduce the error Type `=INT("")` in any cell

To fix this handle blank values

Updated Answer:

```
Function Formula2Text(ByRef myCell As Range) As String
Dim QuestionId As Integer
Dim strInput As String

'Get Formula instead of values
strInput = myCell.FormulaR1C1

'Use Regex to Catch all ID's
 Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 Set rnglookup = Worksheets("questionlist").Range("A3:F2537")
  Regex.Global = True
  Regex.Pattern = "\d+"     

For Each Match In Regex.Execute(strInput)

    'Skip if the ID is 100
    If (Match.Value <> 100) Then QuestionId = Match.Value

    'Lookup ID in the rnglookup,Make sure the Ids are sorted in asc in the questionlist sheet
    Qntxt = Application.VLookup(QuestionId, rnglookup, 5, False)

    If IsError(Qntxt) Then Qntxt = "Missing Lookup"

   'Replace the ID with the lookup
    strInput = Replace(strInput, QuestionId, Qntxt)

Next
Formula2Text = strInput

End Function
```

Usage:In the cell next to the formula use the function by referencing the formula

```
 =Formula2Text(A1)
```

Comment: To be honest with you. I am not sure how to do that. I am very new to vba. any guidance you provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I still cant figure out what you are trying to-do, Pls edit your question to emphasize the problem than the error , then someone can help!

Comment: I have to excel sheets
first sheet has formulas like this (20054/18393)*100.0
Second sheet has an ID column and a text column
the ID column corresponds with the 5 digit numbers in the formula above.
What I am trying to do is create a new column on sheet 1 copying the formulas but instead of having the ids in the formula it would have the text that correspond to the ID

Does that clear it up a bit.

Comment: I think I got it now!

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The other thing is not all the formulas are the same. some formulas may look like this
(11778/(13214+11740+11748+11778))*100